# Calculate Normal Vector

Tags: c++, math, 3d, directx, hlsl

Is it possible to calculate my mesh normal vector when I have just TANGENT and BINORMAL vectors ?

```
      float4 Binormal : BINORMAL ;
      float4 Tangent  : TANGENT  ;
      float4 Position : POSITION ;
```

Comment: You're going to have to provide more information than that.

Comment: Generally it makes more sense to encode the Normal as a float3, and then tangent as a float4 with the .w component set to a 1.0 or -1.0 sign. Then you can reconstruct the binormal in the shader. See [Lengyel’s Method](http://www.terathon.com/code/tangent.html) and [DirectXMesh](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=324981).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I understand it, a binormal vector is defined from the normal and tangent vectors through a cross product :

[image: binormal = tangent x normal]

Thus `normal = binormal x tangent`, that is, what you wrote is correct.

Since according to the doc, [the cross product is defined for vectors of size 3](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb509585%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), you can do the following :

```
normal = float4(cross(binormal.xyz, tangent.xyz), 1.0);
```

This is using the cross product from HLSL, which I recommend. But to get into more detail, you are not actually performing a [real cross product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product).

The real formula should be the following, where u is `binormal`, v is `tangent` and `s` is `normal` :

[image: formula of cross product]

Thus the code for a cross product should, instead, be :

```
normal.x = binormal.y*tangent.z - binormal.z*tangent.y;
normal.y = binormal.z*tangent.x - binormal.x*tangent.z;
normal.z = binormal.x*tangent.y - binormal.y*tangent.x;
```

And an alternate, swizzled version (that returns a vector of size 3, use `float4(..., 1.0)` if you want a 4 item vector) :

```
normal = binormal.yzx*tangent.zxy - binormal.zxy*tangent.yzx;
```